# Vue3 split form into components avoiding mutating props

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3, code-splitting, vue-props

I've created a component which does a lot of work:

- Receives data from API
- Populate so many inputs with this data
- Manages the form submission doing the API post with data inside inputs

So the component is working but I'd like to split into small components, my idea was something like:

- ViewForm: Receives Data from API and pass down to sub components. Submit form doing the POST call.
- SubFormA: Show a group of inputs related with "section A" and populate with props passed from ViewForm.
- SubFormB: Same but with "Section B"
- can be more subForms...

`viewForm`

```
<template>
  <sub-form-a v-model="formA"></sub-form-a>
  <sub-form-b v-model="formB"></sub-form-b>
  <button @click="submitHandler">Send</button>
</template>
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'

let formA = ref({ //This data would come from an API call, but for showing the example.
  a: "aaaa",
  b: "bbbb",
})
let formB = ref({ c: "cccc", d: "dddd" })

function submitHandler(){
  // Here I should have variables formA and formB updated with that user entered on the inputs.
}
</script>
```

`subFormA` // `subFormB`

```
<template>
  <input v-model="modelValue.a" type="text" />
  <input v-model="modelValue.b" type="text" />
</template>
<script setup>
  const props = defineProps(["modelValue"]);
  // validate inputs with rules
</script>
```

Eslint warns me with the popular problem:
`ESLint: Unexpected mutation of "modelValue" prop.(vue/no-mutating-props)`

It's weird because devtools doesn't show me this warning... Vue3 removed this warning or I'm missing something?

I've read a lot of this problem but I'm still don't understand...

Why is this an anti-pattern? I saw a lot of examples where I see the problem, but with my example, it's a form, this is not what we want? that the child can directly modify the props? I see no problem here, I want that the parent component can overwrite all inputs with props, but at the same time childs modify the parent data, so then parent component can submit the form easily.

So how can I fix this?
Should child components clone the props and using their local data to populate the inputs and watch all inputs and emit the data? But then the parent component will have to create another variable to receive the updated data right? Like:

`viewForm`

```
<template>
  <sub-form-a :data="formA" @update="updateFormAHandler"></sub-form-a>
  <sub-form-b :data="formB" @update="updateFormBHandler"></sub-form-b>
  <button @click="submitHandler">Send</button>
</template>
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'

let formA = ref({ //This data would come from an API call, but for showing the example.
  a: "aaaa",
  b: "bbbb",
})
let formB = ref({ c: "cccc", d: "dddd" })

let formAUpdated = ref({})
let formBUpdated = ref({})

function updateFormAHandler(data){
  formAUpdated = data
}

function updateFormBHandler(data){
  formBUpdated = data
}

function submitHandler(){
  // Here I should have variables formA and formB updated with that user entered on the inputs.

  // Submit formAUpdated and formBUpdated.
}
</script>
```

This is the way? I feel a bit confusing...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to emit anything from your component in your scenario, you're simply binding the data. Emit would be used for triggering custom events on the parent, like closing pop-ups (for example).

In your component, you don't want to mutate the data but you want to update a *local* version of it as per Vue rules. This can be done with a computed property in your component like so:

```
computed: {
    localFormA() {
        return this.formA
    },
},
```

And then use **localFormA** in your component to bind to the inputs as normal, so you're not mutating the original prop being passed down.

```
<input type="text" v-model="localFormA.myProperty"/>
```

In your parent, you pass down **formA** as a prop:

```
<sub-form-a :formA="formA"></sub-form-a>
```

Comment: Yes it's working but I don't understand what is happening behind the scenes. It is not exactly the same as mutating the props directly? It seems we using the computed variable only for avoiding Eslint warning... I mean the variable on parent component is two bind way, if child modifies the data, parent receives the changes too (as I wanted) but for this reason I think it's the same as mutating the props directy

Comment: It's 'the Vue way', they suggest the same solution in their docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html?redirect=true#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: The guide shows 2 options for not mutating props but it is not considering that parent needs the value updated for child component. In fact it explains the reason why we should not do it. And for majority of the cases it's okay, parent component just pass down props. But in my case I want that parent pass down props and submits the data modified by child component. Seems I'm using the vue anti-pattern... but at the same time I prefer that which component gets data must submit too. I'm a bit confused 